# Preserve file ownership while copying [tcl]

Tags: tcl

I am trying to copy a file to a destination using tcl.

```
file copy $filename $destination
```

However, I want the file ownership to be preserved while copying the file.

Eg: `file copy file1.txt file2.txt`

```
ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 reshma root 0 Jan 10 08:34 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root 0 Jan 10 08:34 file2.txt
```

How do I preserve the file ownership while copying?

Comment: Does https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/file.htm help? What you need is to figure out how to change ownership of a file in tcl. The fact you've copied it is irrelevant, all files created by your program are owned by your program's user context.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615492/tcl-equivalent-for-unix-cp-pl-command/40616939#40616939

Comment: tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/file.htm does not have options for file copy to preserve/set the file ownership. Using 'exec cp -p $from $to' helps though. Thanks! :)